# App wide size units on Android?

Tags: android, text-size, density-independent-pixel

please is there a way how to change the DP or SP scale factor globally for an application on Android? 
I have quite complex layout based on SPs, but I would also like to let users scale it manually..is there a way how to do that? Now they just can do it through global system settings
I mean something like app specific SP scale or so..

Thanks

Comment: dp is Device dependant and cannot or at least should not be changed by the user.

Comment: I mean scaling it..that can be done also device independently..